# Why is this type of hesitation considered unethical?

Tags: bridge

In two previous questions, it was clearly agreed that hesitating before playing a singleton specifically, and hesitating during play as a bluff generally constitute "wrongful/unethical hesitation." As an advanced beginner, I don't understand this rule at all.

I know that at the highest level, the best way to play and not give away any information about your holding to the opponents is to play each card at a nice even tempo. I am not a world class player; I am not even an advanced player (if I endplay you, I promise it wasn't intentional). As such, I frequently need to pause and calculate what to play, even in situations where the correct play should be obvious.

Knowing that I will inevitably need to pause and consider a play and that that pause will provide my opponents with the information that I had a potentially difficult decision to make, why is it considered unethical for me to occasionally insert a similar pause before a routine play?

It isn't as if I could use such a pause to reliably signal something to my partner. In fact, this strategy removes the temptation for partner to draw unauthorized inferences from my pauses.

Comment: I don't play bridge, but something sounds really off to me about this "rule".  In any other game I know, if you somehow suggested that giving false tells was immoral, you'd be laughed at like a scrub.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you routinely take 2-3 seconds before each play of the cards, that is ethical. If you usually play cards more quickly, but take a pause when you have a problem, that is ethical.

If, on the other hand, you usually play cards more quickly, take a pause when you have a problem, and sometimes take a pause when you don't have a problem to throw declarer off, this is unethical. Even though your partner is not entitled to know when you have a problem, declarer *is* entitled to know. Pausing in order to mislead declarer is called "coffee-housing." It is unethical because in bridge only your actual plays should mislead declarer. It is related to the idea that you and your partner may not have secret bidding agreements. Bridge is not poker; you are not trying to bluff your opponents based on your demeanor.

Comment: Well, actually it is quite proper to bluff your opponents; just not by the *way* you play your cards or make calls, only by the actual cards played and calls made.

Comment: Quite right. I've modified the last sentence to reflect this.

Comment: I knew this was the agreed upon answer when I asked the question, but I don't think it addresses the real thrust of my question which is WHY this is the agreed upon standard. That is why I haven't accepted this answer. You assert that declarer is entitled to know when I have a problem. I'm really not sure why. This isn't so much bluffing a la poker as it is removing a tell. I simply don't understand why my opponents are allowed to infer information from my demeanor but I'm not allowed to then stop them from doing that.

Comment: To wit, I AM allowed to deceive declarer with my choice of which card to play. This seems incredibly counter-intuitive. Knowing you cannot stop the contract and making an odd play with the intent of disrupting Declarer is just as much of a bluff. I don't see how its related to not having secret agreements. There, I always thought the intent was to stop saying one thing to partner but something else to the opponents. Here, I'm trying to conceal information from everyone (partner included, perhaps).

Comment: A sufficiently advanced defender can anticipate problems and remove the tells by deciding ahead of time how to play. The laws of contract bridge were written by people whose goal was to minimize distractions from bridge as an intellectual problem. Allowing coffee housing introduces a social problem that distracts from the logic puzzle that is a bridge hand. Ideal bridge is played as if by robots, with each action taken in tempo.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll +1 to ruds.  Your partner is not allowed to infer from your "hitches" (or hesitations if you like) during bidding or play.  But your opponents are.  This prevents passing of "unauthorized information" (UI) to your partner.  Your opponents draw conclusions at their own risk.  But you're not allowed to do this to trick your opponents--which the answer has already covered.  You really should accept this answer.

Comment: @HostileFork Thanks for reminding me. I still find this particular element of Bridge ethics to be not well supported by any general principle of what should/shuld not be considered ethical, but this is the accepted answer and Bridge players have no time for my philosophical objections.

Answer (score 3):

Bridge players derive pleasure from using their brains, be it a technical play, or some nice logic to read the cards perfectly, which includes inferences from opponents hesitations.

Allowing coffee-housing like invalid hesitations just destroys that pleasure, as now there is garbage thrown into the pool of inferences available. That said, beginning players usually hesitate for no valid bridge reason, and many better players indeed try to take that into account.

Note that is very different from deceptive plays in bridge, where you deceive the opponents purely using the card you play (and not in the manner you play it), are completely ethical and quite a useful weapon.

Comment: Just trying to give some reason as to why it is considered unethical...

Comment: But doesn't allowing defenders to make a play which deceives Declarer already 'throw garbage into the pool?' Why such a stark contrast between play and manner of play? I mean, I'm not even suggesting that one should play so as to intentionally deceive Declarer. I'm only suggesting that one should vary one's play so that Declarer can't possibly draw an inference. The intent is quite different.

Comment: It's very strange. It's like you're asking Defenders to 'hang themselves.' I mean, by this logic it should also be unethical to play quickly, without thinking about any difficulties, in a situation where one really does have a problem that might be figured out if defender took extra time to think. It's like we've created a situation where defenders have to help Declarer beat them, otherwise the defenders are acting unethically.

Comment: @KevinDriscoll: Nope. Falsecards don't put garbage in the pool. For instance, AKQ9x opposite xxx. You need to make 5 tricks from the suite. You play a low card to the A. RHO follows with the J. If RHO is a weak defender you finesse the 9 the next round (restricted choice), but if RHO is a good defender you should consider the play for the drop. Consider the same situation where RHO thinks for a while and follows the J. Ultimately he turns out to have a singleton J (where he had no reason to be thinking).

Comment: @Kevin: That is why they advise you to take your time at trick 1. You are entitled to do some thinking upfront. Once you gain more information mid-hand, you can always pause to think about the whole hand. Some people recommend playing a card face down in normal tempo, and doing the thinking, saying "thinking about the hand". You don't have to coffee-house, and you won't be hanged, and as a side effect, planning ahead will improve your results!

Comment: With AKQ9x opposite xxx I can cash a 2nd one in case they are 4-1 once East has put in the jack.. Anyway I always remember a hand where I was defending and Dick Shek was declaring, I was on his left and dummy had AK10xx and no entries in a suit. He led towards the holding and I thought just a bit with Qxx then threw the queen in. He ducked and finessed the 10 next round. When it lost to the jack he made no tricks at all from the suit losing 2.. His contract did go down..

Comment: @CashCow: Right, you can cash the second round. Say it was four tricks needed with AKQ9 opposite xx or something. btw, well done on the Q play (haven't heard of Dick Shek, sorry).

Answer (score 1):

It's related to the 'secret agreements' with partner in this way -   Dummy has  KJ.   Declarer leads toward it,  and has a the AQ guess.  If you hesitate as if thinking of hopping up with the ACE, declarer will be fooled ( what else could you be thinking of?) but your partner won't , he's looking at the ACE !!     Similarly, if dummy J43 of trumps and declarer, holding AK1076, leads the J  and his right hand opponent hesitates as if he was thinking of covering with the Queen ( what else could he be thinking of?) then declare will be fooled but your partner can't be - he's looking at the Queen!.    You were never at risk for fooling your partner.